# Recording Audio and Playing sound at the same time - C# - Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows

I am trying to record audio and play it directly (I want to hear my voice in the headphone without saving it) however the MediaElement and the MediaCapture seems non to work at the same time.
I initialized my MediaCapture so:

```
    _mediaCaptureManager = new MediaCapture();
    var settings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
    settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
    settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other;
    settings.AudioProcessing = AudioProcessing.Default;
    await _mediaCaptureManager.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

However I don't really know how to proceed; I am wonderign if one of these ways could work (I tryied implement them without success, and I have not found examples):

1. Is there a way to use StartPreviewAsync() recording Audio, or it only works for Videos? I noticed that I get the following error:"The specified object or value does not exist" while setting my CaptureElement Source; it only happens if I write "settings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;" while everyting works for .Video.
2. How can I record to a stream using StartRecordToStreamAsync(); I mean, how have I to initialize the IRandomAccessStream and read from it? Can I *write* on a stream while I keep *reading* for it?
3. I read that changing AudioCathegory of the MediaElement and the MediaCathegory of the MediaCapture to Communication there is a possibility it could work. However, while my code works (it just have to record and save in a file) with the previous setting, it don't works if I wrote "settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Communication;" instead of "settings.MediaCategory = MediaCategory.Other;". Can you tell me why?
   Here is my current program that just record, save and play:

   ```
   private async void CaptureAudio()
   {
       try
       {
          _recordStorageFile = await KnownFolders.VideosLibrary.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);                      
         MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWav(AudioEncodingQuality.Auto);
         await _mediaCaptureManager.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, this._recordStorageFile);
         _recording = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           Debug.WriteLine("Failed to capture audio:"+e.Message);
        }
   }

   private async void StopCapture()
   {
      if (_recording)
      {
         await _mediaCaptureManager.StopRecordAsync();
         _recording = false;
      }
   }

   private async void PlayRecordedCapture()
   {
      if (!_recording)
      {
         var stream = await   _recordStorageFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
         playbackElement1.AutoPlay = true;
         playbackElement1.SetSource(stream, _recordStorageFile.FileType);
         playbackElement1.Play();
      }
   }
   ```

If you have any suggestion I'll be gratefull.
Have a good day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you consider targeting Windows 10 instead? The new AudioGraph API allows you to do just this, and the [Scenario 2 (Device Capture) in the SDK sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) demonstrates it well.

First, the sample populates all output devices into a list:

```
private async Task PopulateDeviceList()
{
    outputDevicesListBox.Items.Clear();
    outputDevices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(MediaDevice.GetAudioRenderSelector());
    outputDevicesListBox.Items.Add("-- Pick output device --");
    foreach (var device in outputDevices)
    {
        outputDevicesListBox.Items.Add(device.Name);
    }
}
```

Then it gets to building the AudioGraph:

```
AudioGraphSettings settings = new AudioGraphSettings(AudioRenderCategory.Media);
settings.QuantumSizeSelectionMode = QuantumSizeSelectionMode.LowestLatency;

// Use the selected device from the outputDevicesListBox to preview the recording
settings.PrimaryRenderDevice = outputDevices[outputDevicesListBox.SelectedIndex - 1];

CreateAudioGraphResult result = await AudioGraph.CreateAsync(settings);

if (result.Status != AudioGraphCreationStatus.Success)
{
    // TODO: Cannot create graph, propagate error message
    return;
}

AudioGraph graph = result.Graph;

// Create a device output node
CreateAudioDeviceOutputNodeResult deviceOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceOutputNodeAsync();
if (deviceOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
{
    // TODO: Cannot create device output node, propagate error message
    return;
}

deviceOutputNode = deviceOutputNodeResult.DeviceOutputNode;

// Create a device input node using the default audio input device
CreateAudioDeviceInputNodeResult deviceInputNodeResult = await graph.CreateDeviceInputNodeAsync(MediaCategory.Other);

if (deviceInputNodeResult.Status != AudioDeviceNodeCreationStatus.Success)
{
    // TODO: Cannot create device input node, propagate error message
    return;
}

deviceInputNode = deviceInputNodeResult.DeviceInputNode;

// Because we are using lowest latency setting, we need to handle device disconnection errors
graph.UnrecoverableErrorOccurred += Graph_UnrecoverableErrorOccurred;

// Start setting up the output file
FileSavePicker saveFilePicker = new FileSavePicker();
saveFilePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Pulse Code Modulation", new List<string>() { ".wav" });
saveFilePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Windows Media Audio", new List<string>() { ".wma" });
saveFilePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("MPEG Audio Layer-3", new List<string>() { ".mp3" });
saveFilePicker.SuggestedFileName = "New Audio Track";
StorageFile file = await saveFilePicker.PickSaveFileAsync();

// File can be null if cancel is hit in the file picker
if (file == null)
{
    return;
}

MediaEncodingProfile fileProfile = CreateMediaEncodingProfile(file);

// Operate node at the graph format, but save file at the specified format
CreateAudioFileOutputNodeResult fileOutputNodeResult = await graph.CreateFileOutputNodeAsync(file, fileProfile);

if (fileOutputNodeResult.Status != AudioFileNodeCreationStatus.Success)
{
    // TODO: FileOutputNode creation failed, propagate error message
    return;
}

fileOutputNode = fileOutputNodeResult.FileOutputNode;

// Connect the input node to both output nodes
deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(fileOutputNode);
deviceInputNode.AddOutgoingConnection(deviceOutputNode);
```

Once all of that is done, you can record to a file while at the same time playing the recorded audio like so:

```
private async Task ToggleRecordStop()
{
    if (recordStopButton.Content.Equals("Record"))
    {
        graph.Start();
        recordStopButton.Content = "Stop";
    }
    else if (recordStopButton.Content.Equals("Stop"))
    {
        // Good idea to stop the graph to avoid data loss
        graph.Stop();
        TranscodeFailureReason finalizeResult = await fileOutputNode.FinalizeAsync();
        if (finalizeResult != TranscodeFailureReason.None)
        {
            // TODO: Finalization of file failed. Check result code to see why, propagate error message
            return;
        }

        recordStopButton.Content = "Record";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. So, since I was writing a Windows Phone App, i'll have to wait for the release of Windows 10 Mobile, haven't I? These classes I need to build the AudioGraph and so on, will just add to Visual Studio through an update or I have to download something? Sorry but I am not yet confident with Visual Studio...

Comment: You'll have to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 to develop for Windows 10 (there's a free Community edition). You can also join the Windows Insiders program to upgrade your phone to Windows 10 and get going on the development and get a head start.

Comment: Great, I installed Visual Studio 2015 and now I have namespaces I need to understand those samples. But now I have another question: how can I download that project you sent me (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation)? I can't really find a way to download the zip file (the page doesn't show me any button)..

Comment: If you go to the root of the repository (here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples), there's a "Download ZIP" button on the right. But you should learn a little more about github, it offers functionality you may like.

Comment: Does this project actually work for anyone? When I run it, I get feedback through my speakers, and it saves a file that has data in it, but it won't playback with anything.

Comment: The feedback is expected, as you're playing back what you capture. What happens if you plug in headphones instead?